# when passing JSON request ajax call failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling fallowing function

```
function checkUser(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "assets/json/login.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {name:"XYZ",status:'A'},          
        success: function(data)
        {
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(obj.status);
            if(obj.status == 200)
            {
                window.location='dashboard.html'
            }else
            {
                    $("#error").html(obj.msg);
                    return false;
            }

        },

     error: function(errorThrown){
            alert("There is an error with AJAX!" + errorThrown);
    } 
});

}
```

In response, the **error** function is called. Json file contain status and message like {status:"200",msg:"SUCCESS"}

**EDIT**
I corrected my json. Now it look like this {"status":"200","msg":"SUCCESS"}
Now its calling Success function. But Its giving following error on obj = JSON.parse(data);

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

Here response is already in json format so I think no need to parse it. But then how to display status ?

Comment: try `parseInt(obj.status)==200` or `obj.status=='200'` inside `if`

Comment: Why are you performing a `POST` to local assets?

Comment: @Swordfish0321 — Why not? Most POST requests go to local URLs. It would be odd making a POST request to a *static* file, but assuming that a URL is handled with a static file just because it has `.json` at the end is an assumption that isn't always correct.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. And most "ajax" POST requests certainly do not go to local URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Will making response keys as string helps? Instead of

```
{status:"200",msg:"SUCCESS"}
```

can you try

```
{"status":"200","msg":"SUCCESS"}
```

Comment: Yes. JSON property names must be strings, not identifiers. `{status:"200",msg:"SUCCESS"}` isn't JSON so it fails JSON parsing and triggers the error handling. The correct way to solve this is to generate the JSON using a JSON library and not by adding in the quote characters by hand.

Comment: If I wrote it as it above then its giving SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data  error

Comment: @Aanshi — That's a different problem. You have successfully caused it to stop hitting the error function and to call the success function instead.

Comment: Damn, I didn't notice that was an invalid json. I deserved my downvotes :)

Comment: @Aanshi — jQuery will parse JSON for you and the value passed into the success function is the result of that and not the raw string of JSON. Since it isn't raw JSON, you can't parse it as such.

Answer (score -3):

You're expecting a JSON in the dataType. You're receiving a JSON. So no need to parse it. Remove `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: I tried it .But its called error function instead of success

Comment: What does `login.json` return exactly? Try to `console.log` the response.

Comment: Json file will return status like this {status:200}

Comment: First of all I have to post my data and if transaction successful done then i''ll get the response  of that . So I think it'll not work for this case

Comment: So maybe that's what you're doing wrong. You're fetching a json file, right? This is just data. Not code. Why are you passing data to some other data? It's just a json, it won't do anything with the data you pass it. Would it be a PHP file or something, I would understand, but passing data to a json file makes no sense.

Comment: Removing the JSON.parse step will be needed to solve the OP's **next** problem, but not the current one. Switching to `.getJSON` is pointless at best (it saves some typing which has already been done) and harmful at worst (since you are switching from making a POST request to making a GET request). You shouldn't assume that a URL points to a static file just because it has `.json` in it.

Comment: So what is it then? We need OP's light here. That would be a PHP file with a .json extension? If so, what for?

Comment: @JeremyThille: Yes you are right. No need to parse the JSON. Its json file using this  server read the details and send response.

Comment: So? Do you have the answer? What's in this file? It has a .json extension, but what is it? PHP? How does that work?